# The continuity of infimum of a function

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a connected metric space and $(Y,d')$ is a compact metric space. Let $f$ be a continuous function from $(X\times Y,\max(d,d'))$ into $\mathbb{R}$. Because $Y$ is compact we can define:

$$g(x)=\inf_{y\in Y}f(x,y)$$

for all $x\in X$. I need to prove that $g$ is continuous.

First I tried to prove that if $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}\rightarrow a$ is a convergent sequences in $X$, $(g(x_n))_{n\ge 0}$ converges to $g(a)$. I arrived at showing that $(g(x_n))_{n\ge 0}$ has only one adherent value, which is $g(a)$, but no more.

Then I tried to use the fact that for fixed $x$, the function $f(x,y)$ is uniformly continuous in $y$, but there was not so much progress.

In either attempts, I never used the connectedness of $X$, so I think that's the key, but I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: What does the statement "Let $f$ be continuous function from $(X\times Y, \max(d,d'))$ into $\mathbb{R}$."  mean?  I don't understand the meaning of the $\max(d,d')$ thing.

Comment: The metric associated with $X\times Y$ is $d((x;y);(a;b))=\max(d(x,a),d'(y',b))$

Comment: A remark: the statement is easy to prove is $X$ is locally compact.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22697/projection-map-being-a-closed-map

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247542/projection-is-an-open-map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the topology induced by the metric $\max(d,d')$ is just the product topology. That means we have continuous open projections $\pi_X: X\times Y\to X$ and $\pi_Y: X\times Y\to Y$.

Show that the preimage of an open subbase set $(a,\infty)$ under $g$ is open: This is the set $X-\{x\mid \exists y\in Y,f(x,y)\le a\}$. The complement can be expressed as $\pi_X(f^{-1}((\infty,a]))$. Since $(\infty,a]$ is closed, its preimage under $f$ is closed. Applying the projection $\pi_{\Bbb R}$, we get a closed set again. This is because the projection $X\times Y\to X$ is closed if $Y$ is compact.

For an open subbase set $(\infty,a)$, its preimage under $g$ is the set $\{x\mid \exists y\in Y,f(x,y)<a\}$, which is $\pi_X(f^{-1}((\infty,a)))$.

Connectedness of $X$ is not needed.

See also [Continuity of max (moving the domain and the function)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426106/continuity-of-max-moving-the-domain-and-the-function), for a similar result.

Comment: why is the projection of an open set is open?

Comment: @Mr.T: In the product space $X\times Y$ each open set $W$ is a union of open products of the form $U\times V$, where $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$. The projection of such a product is $U$ in $X$, or $V$ if you project to $Y$. So the projection of $W$ is a union of open sets.