# Let $m(x) = \min_{t\in[a, x]}f(t)$. $f(x)$ is continuous on $x\in[a, b]$. Prove $m(x)$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $x\in[a, b]$. Let:
>   $$
> m(x) = \min_{t\in[a, x]}f(t)\\
> M(x) = \max_{t\in[a,x]}f(t)
> $$
>   Prove both $m(x)$ and $M(x)$ are continuous.

This statement seems so obvious, but I was not able to write down a formal proof.

There is a couple of trivial facts I've figured out so far. First by definition of $\min x$ we know it is monotonically decreasing. Also $f(x)$ is bounded and by Bolzano-Weierstrass there exists $x_0\in[a,b]$ such that:
$$
f(x_0) = \inf_{[a, b]}f
$$

So we might only consider the interval $[a, x_0]$, because $m(x)$ is going to be constant for $x \ge x_0$. Similar facts are true for $M(x)$.

I've also been playing around with the following inequalities without any success:
$$
\min_{x\in[a,b]} f(x) \le \min_{t\in[a, x]} f(t) \le f(x) \le \max_{t\in[a, x]} f(t) \le \max_{x\in[a,b]} f(x)
$$

What would be a way to prove the statement?

Comment: Did you try with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you are right, there is a typo. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Even more general: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/426106/42969.

Comment: Sorry, my hint is wrong. For example, if $f(x)=x^2$ on $[-2,2],$ then $f(-1)=f(1), $ but $m(-1)=1\neq 0=m(1).$ @roman